# Why my react app fails on production build after upgrading to react 16?

Tags: reactjs

Why my react app fails on production build after upgrading to react 16 ?

After upgrading react to version 16 my app stoped working on production build, when running development works fine. If I downgrade to React 15.6 it still works fine on both prod and dev enviroments.

I am using: `"webpack": "^3.5.6",` and `"react": "^16.0.0",`

I am getting the following error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**
[image]

My webpack prod configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const config = require("./webpack.base.babel");

const OfflinePlugin = require('offline-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(config, {
  // devtool: "nosources-source-map",
  devtool: "source-map",
  // In production, we skip all hot-reloading stuff
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill', // Needed for redux-saga es6 generator support
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/client/app.js'), // Start with app.js
  ],
  performance: {
    assetFilter: (assetFilename) => !(/(\.map$)|(^(main\.|favicon\.))/.test(assetFilename)),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/client/index.html",
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),
    // Shared code
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      children: true,
      minChunks: 2,
      async: true,
    }),
    // Avoid publishing files when compilation fails
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // Put it in the end to capture all the HtmlWebpackPlugin's
    // assets manipulations and do leak its manipulations to HtmlWebpackPlugin
    new OfflinePlugin({
      relativePaths: false,
      publicPath: '/',

      // No need to cache .htaccess. See http://mxs.is/googmp,
      // this is applied before any match in `caches` section
      excludes: ['.htaccess'],

      caches: {
        main: [':rest:'],

        // All chunks marked as `additional`, loaded after main section
        // and do not prevent SW to install. Change to `optional` if
        // do not want them to be preloaded at all (cached only when first loaded)
        additional: ['*.chunk.js'],
      },

      // Removes warning for about `additional` section usage
      safeToUseOptionalCaches: true,

      AppCache: false,
    }),
  ]
});
```

How can i fix it ?

`webpack.base.babel.js`

```
// Common Webpack configuration used by webpack.config.development and webpack.config.production
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const e2c = require("electron-to-chromium");
const GLOBALS = require('../bin/helpers/globals');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const postcssLoaderOptions = {
  plugins: [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: e2c.electronToBrowserList("1.4")
    }),
  ],
  sourceMap: !isProd,
};

GLOBALS['process.env'].__CLIENT__ = true;

module.exports = {
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[hash].chunk.js',
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    alias: {
      client: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/client"),
      shared: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/shared"),
      server: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/server")
    },
    extensions: [".js", '.jsx', ".json", ".scss"],
    mainFields: ["browser", "module", 'jsnext:main', "main"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /\/Bundles.js/,
      './AsyncBundles.js'
    ),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/vertx/),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      Promise: 'imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.Promise!es6-promise',
      fetch: "imports-loader?this=>global!exports-loader?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch", // fetch API
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "css/[name].[hash].css",
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    noParse: /\.min\.js$/,
    rules: [
      // JavaScript / ES6
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/client"),
          path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/shared"),
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      },
      // Json
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      //HTML
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/client"),
        ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      // Images
      // Inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: {
            limit: 8192,
            name: "images/[name].[ext]?[hash]"
          }
        }
      },
      // Fonts
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      // Styles
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/client"),
          path.resolve(process.cwd(), "src/shared"),
        ],
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:3]'
              }
            },
            {
              loader: "postcss-loader",
              options: postcssLoaderOptions
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                outputStyle: "compressed"
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: `v8.1.1` how does it matter ? i bundle my files and server static content

Comment: Have you tried removing NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin? I'm not sure why you're using it but I don't think it's intended for production setups at all. Maybe it's obscuring the real errror.

Comment: @DanAbramov Yes i tried doesn't help

Comment: What is your "base" config like (`webpack.base.babel`)? It's not included, and might have something that breaks React.

Comment: Why it wiuld brake if its used with develop and works there ? However i will update my question with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix was rly simple.

I just needed to remove this line `noParse: /\.min\.js/`

Which does :

> Prevent webpack from parsing any files matching the given regular
>   expression(s). Ignored files should not have calls to import, require,
>   define or any other importing mechanism.

Comment: Do you know why the production build is not already transpiled?

Comment: @SamSamskies I have no idea :(